# Set position in mediaElement (ScrubbingEnabled alternative in WP8.1)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to set position of video while video is paused.
In WPF it is simple with **ScrubbingEnabled** 
property.
But there is nothing like this for windows phone.
So I use:

```
_mediaElement.Play();
_mediaElement.Position += new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,50);//move video 50 milisecond forward
_mediaElement.Pause();
```

It is "working", but when I am trying to go (about)5 miliseconds back, it is moving forward and it is not clear solution...

How can I replace **ScrubbingEnabled** property on windows phone?

### Edit

Code for 5ms back:

```
_mediaElement.Play();
_mediaElement.Position -= new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,5);
_mediaElement.Pause();
```

Comment: Can you show the code for going 5 milliseconds back? That's where you see issues, right?

Comment: issue is, that solution is not clear - and it is the reason why it is not working for 5ms back (video is playing forward, when time is changing)

Comment: Have you tried this: _mediaElement.Position += new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,-5);

Comment: This is not solving problem. For example: _mediaElement.Position -= new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,50); is moving back... But it is not precisely 50ms  (I guess it is something about 44, depends on computer performance)

Comment: I see. Well, that would be my next guess - the 5 milliseconds is just too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is not exactly the answer, but today WP8.1 is obsolete and setting position with mediaElement on Windows 10 work pretty fine without Play-Pause hack.
So:

```
_mediaElement.Position -= new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,33);
```

is moving video 1 frame back (30 FPS video), and

```
_mediaElement.Position -= new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,5);
```

is not moving anywhere.

**One interesting thing:**

To move 1 frame you need to change position at least one half of frame time.

```
_mediaElement.Position -= new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,16);//not moving
_mediaElement.Position -= new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,17);//moving every 2nd "click"
```

*Frame time for 30 FPS video is 1000/30 = 33.333 ms*

Answer (score 1):

Even assuming that your video is running at 60 frames per second, there's only one frame every 16.67 ms. So to move 5 ms should probably do nothing in many cases.

That would also explain why when you ask it to move 50 ms, it doesn't move by that exact amount, but rather goes to the time of the closest frame.

(if you move position by only a few frames, due to how digital video compression works it might not work as you expect either)

Comment: So it means that my solution (play-change position-pause) is the best way how to change position in mediaElement while paused?